# Issue in listing all virtual directories in IIS 6 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I am trying to list all the virtual directories in IIS using powershell.
I am running the following script:

```
$AvailableWebApps = Get-WmiObject IIsWebVirtualDir -Namespace "ROOT\MicrosoftIISv2" |
    Where-Object { $_.name -like "W3SVC/1/*" }

foreach ($item in $AvailableWebApps)
{
    $currentAppName = $item.Name.replace("W3SVC/1/ROOT/","")
    Write-Host $currentAppName
}
```

The virtual directories are not listing and I am able to see only one: W3SVC/1/ROOT

This script is working fine on all other servers. Only in one server I am facing an issue.
Is there anything I need to check into?

Additional info:
IIS Version 6.0
Running with admin privileges

Comment: I could re-create your issue by running the command against my SharePoint servers. When I ran `Get-WmiObject IIsWebVirtualDir -Namespace "ROOT\MicrosoftIISv2" | Select Name` without the `Where-Object` clause, I noticed that everything was under `W3SVC/2/ROOT` (notice the 2 instead of 1). You may be in a similar situation.

Comment: Thank you..That worked in one machine. Let me check in my laptop and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re-Posting comment as an answer)

I could re-create your issue by running the command against my SharePoint servers. When I ran:

```
Get-WmiObject IIsWebVirtualDir -Namespace "ROOT\MicrosoftIISv2" | Select Name
```

Without the `Where-Object` clause, I noticed that everything was under `W3SVC/2/ROOT` (notice the 2 instead of 1).

You may be in a similar situation.